# How to capture the arguments passed to an .exe when is called by another program? (Windows)

Tags: windows, python, debug

I have two programs:

When A.exe is running, it calls B.exe with a series of arguments.

Any suggestions as to how can I see these arguments? I could write another
B.exe program to do that, but it sounds more complicated than it needs to be.

Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at `Process Explorer`, which comes from sysinternals.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: and what if process lives < 2 secs, so Process Explorer wont just show it even if refresh timeout is large?

Comment: @mhambra, in that case, the OP should write another `B.exe` that just logs the passed arguments.

Comment: sure.. just thought of some universal profiler for tracing mingw's compilations (not c:\bin\sh).

Comment: @mhambra, in that case, `apimon` and set filter on `CreateProcess` calls maybe helps, but I didn't try it myself cuz I'm in Debian now. I found this: http://goo.gl/hWrvE so called `strace` for Win32 but I didn't test it so not sure if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows SDK has xperf.exe and it can trace process calls too. Not sure. Not a Win* man.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on Windows an Linux, but I'm not sure:

```
import sys
print sys.argv #This prints a list of all arguments
if '--option' in sys.argv:
    pass #do something
```